# Excel array function return all fields found with index and match

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Here is the array function I am using:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$D$2:$D$153,MATCH(1,(B9='Master Data'!$J$2:$J$153)*('Master Data'!$W$2:$W$153=1),FALSE)),"")
```

Where D is the name of a project, J is a persons name and W is a flag to check if they are assigned to a project either equal to 0 or 1. B is also an instance of the persons name that is built up from a seperate list.

It basically references the master data and returns any rows with the criteria specified. However a single person may have two instances where the assigned flag is equal to 1 and thus as the master data is filtered different results are given back by the function.

Another problem I have is that the persons name is not repeated either so maybe the best way would be to start populating the names in the assigned table from the master data as well.

As requested here is an slight example of the data. On the left is the master data, the middle is the assigned table thats being built and the right is the list of employees that builds up the names in the assigned table.

[image: Data sample]

Please note that there is two instances of david smith in the master data but only one in the assigned table as its being built with the employees list.

What I was thinking was to build up the names in the assigned table from the master data using an array where the assigned indicator is equal to 1 and to completely scrap the employees list, but I'm really unsure if this is possible or how to go about it.

Or even if there was some sort of way to select a few columns from the master data where the assigned indicator = 1?

Comment: Are you saying that there are blank cells where a name should be referencing a project? Perhaps you can post 6-10 rows of redacted sample data.

Comment: Added a bit of sample data there so you could get a better insight to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood it right. But the problem how to list multiple lookup results is achievable with SMALL function in combination with getting an array of ROW numbers.

For example have a sheet like this:

[image]

Then formulas are:

F4 downwards:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$E4,$C:$C,1)
```

G4 and then copied in G4:J8:

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$1000=$E4,IF($C$1:$C$1000=1,ROW($1:$1000))),COLUMN(A:A)))}
```

But if the goal is only to have a filtered list of all assigned resources, then the formulas could be

E13:

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,MATCH(1,($C$1:$C$1000=1)*1,0))}
```

E14 downwards:

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($E$13:$E13,$B$1:$B$1000)=0)*($C$1:$C$1000=1),0))}
```

Formulas in `{}` are array formulas. These are entered into the cell without the curly brackets and then [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] is pressed to finish.

I have not handled the error values for better understanding the formulas. You can later hide the error values with IFERROR. You seems to know how to do this.

Comment: Hi there I tried using this function using my sample data however when I try to use it by referencing to another sheet it does not seem to work for me.

Your solution works by adding new columns which isnt exactly as I wished but that doesnt matter.

Anyway here is the formula im using to try to reference the master data.

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$D$1:$D$1000,SMALL(IF('Master Data'!$J$1:$J$1000=$E4,IF('Master Data'!$W$1:$W$1000=1,ROW($1:$1000))),COLUMN('Master Data'!A:A))),"")`

Think something wrong with either the row or column functions

Comment: Looks alright if the references are the right ones - this I can't see. What value are you got from the formula? Have you enter it as an array formula?

Comment: It just came up blank, yes tried it as an array formula and yes think all references are correct in the sample sent above is should have been D:D in the column section but no joy

Comment: Your formula cannot be related with your sample image. In your formula `'Master Data'!$D$1:$D$1000` has to be the `Clients` column, `'Master Data'!$J$1:$J$1000` has to be the `Resourcing` column, `'Master Data'!$W$1:$W$1000` has to be the `Assigned Indicator` column and `$E4` of the same sheet in which the formula is entered must contain one name from the Resourcing column.

Comment: Yep thats the way I have it `{=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$D$1:$D$1000,SMALL(IF('Master Data'!$J$1:$J$1000=$B23,IF('Master Data'!$W$1:$W$1000=1,ROW('Master Data'!$1:$1000))),COLUMN('Master Data'!D:D))),"")}`

Just returns an empty cell though unfortunately

Comment: Why is there now `COLUMN('Master Data'!D:D)`? This part is responsible for which SMALLest row number is used. So it has to start with  `A:A` = 1 = first smallest row number. Through copying to right it changes to `B:B`= 2 = second smallest row number and so on.